# To get Woocommerce single-product-page to display information and picture from custom post-type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have to make e-bookstore as an assingment. It has to have a custom post-type Writers, what you can add/edit in the admin area. In the product section when I enter a new product it can be linked with the writer. I made a custom taxonomy writer to link it. I also have to link it the other way aswell. If I add a new writer, I can also link products. I made a custom taxonomy book to link it.

Custom post-types: Products, Writers

Taxonomies: Writers, Books

My question is:

How can I display information about the writer of a specific book in single-product-page?

I tried adding

```
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 

    'custom_taxonomy_description', 70 );
    function custom_taxonomy_description() {
          global $post;
          $writers = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'writers');
          if ($writers) {
          foreach($writers as $writer) {
          echo wpautop($writer->description);
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Add some debug lines to see if your query is returning anything.

Comment: This is wrong, you need to get current product meta and find the linked writer, then do a query based on writer id. You didn't provide enough details to help assist you.

Comment: What details do i need to provide? Thanks for the info